# User location-Android

Tags: java, android, geolocation, location

I am trying to get a users current location and then calculate a distance from the users current location to the long and lat that is read from a database.

After testing my app i have noticed that  the users  location is reading as 0.0 for both long and lat values and thus returning incorrect distance result

I have added all required permissions in the manifest file

```
public class UserLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button b;
private TextView t;
private EditText lo;
private EditText la;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener listener;
double userLat;
double userLong;


String value1  ;
String value2  ;
private String urlString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    lo=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLong);
    la=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtLat);


    String id = "1";
    urlString = "http://10.0.2.2:52387/easyQ.svc/rest/branch/"+id;
    new ProcessJSON().execute(urlString);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    listener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {

            // System.out.println(value1 + " " + value2);
            userLat=location.getLatitude();
            userLong=location.getLongitude();
        }
        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    };
    configure_button();
}

private class ProcessJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
        String stream;
        String urlString = strings[0];

        HTTPDataHandler httpDataHandler = new HTTPDataHandler();
        stream = httpDataHandler.GetHTTPData(urlString);

        return stream;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String stream){
        if(stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(stream);

                  value1 = object.getString("branch_lat");
                  value2 = object.getString("branch_long");
                System.out.println(value1 + " " + value2);
               // t.append("\n " +  distance(userLat,userLong,10,10));
                t.append("\n " +  distance(userLat,userLong,Double.parseDouble(value1),Double.parseDouble(value2)));
                System.out.println("user lat" + userLat);
                System.out.println("user long" + userLong);
                System.out.println("location lat" + value1);
                System.out.println("location long" + value2);
            }
            catch(JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 10:
            configure_button();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void configure_button() {
    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    , 10);
        }
        return;
    }
    // this code won't execute IF permissions are not allowed, because in the line above there is return statement.
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //noinspection MissingPermission
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 5000, 0, listener);











        }
    });
}

private double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
    double theta = lon1 - lon2;
    double dist = Math.sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(theta));
    dist = Math.acos(dist);
    dist = rad2deg(dist);
    dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    return (dist)* 1.609344;
}

private double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}

private double rad2deg(double rad) {
    return (rad * 180.0 / Math.PI);
}



}
```

Comment: SIde note:  Location has the distanceTo function.  No need to do the math yourself, and probably less buggy.

Comment: thank you,will implement that into the function once solved